# Using Nest in MVC.Net Projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elasticsearch, nest

As shown in the document of [NEST](https://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/quick-start.html) I wrote this code to connecting to the elasticsearch rest api.

```
        private static ElasticSearch _elasticSearch;
        private readonly Uri _node;
        private readonly ConnectionSettings _setting;
        private readonly ElasticClient _client;

    private ElasticSearch()
    {
        _node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
        _setting = new ConnectionSettings(_node, defaultIndex: "myprogram");
        _client = new ElasticClient(_setting);
        _client.CreateIndex("myprogram", c => c
            .NumberOfReplicas(0)
            .NumberOfShards(1)
            .Settings(s => s
                .Add("merge.policy.merge_factor", "10")
                .Add("search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.warn", "1s")
            ));
    }
```

and it works perefct in my project. But when I change configure of my project to SSL mode I got an error with this value `Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the stream` on line 4 when I want to create an index. What is the problem?

Comment: May you share how do you set up ssl mode?

Comment: @Rob Thank you  for comment. Yes I have changed SSlEnabled property to true and put RequiredHttps over actions